# centos 7 minimal port 25 closed

Tags: centos7

i have this issue with centos 7 server minimal , if i write : nmap localhost

25/tcp open smtp

or : netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN

tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:220.0.0.0:* LISTEN 969/sshd

tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:250.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1391/master

tcp6 0 0 :::22 :::* LISTEN 969/sshd

tcp6 0 0 ::1:25 :::* LISTEN 1391/master

but if i write from my pc : "telnet server 25 " i get this : Connecting To server ...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed

what is the prblm , any help please

Comment: Good basic troubleshooting.  Your postfix is only listening on localhost.

Comment: Look on the tcp6 lines from netstat -- for sshd it's listening on ':::' -- that's the wildcard/any interface address. on the master line it's listening on '::1' -- that's localhost only.